# How to create shape in android like Image I added?

Tags: android

can anyone please tell me how to create the shape which is somewhat rectangular but at the end it is triangle.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can create this shape programmatically. You'll have to use an asset.

Comment: But using assets I can not give effects to it like this

Comment: You can have all the effects integrated in the asset itself.

Comment: can you tell me, how can I give effects to search bar when someone click It should take whole are for expansion

Comment: Something like http://i.stack.imgur.com/s3F67.png can be achieved by [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the gradient image you have in your drawable folder. Let's call it background.png.
You can do as well with the icons searchicon.png and arrow.png

Then I would use this code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Current Location"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="Mumbai"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/searchicon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not good approach doing it programmatically weather you get you result by using XML Design.

[image]